# Extracting logLik from multiple glmer models into a data frame

Tags: r

I'm trying to make an AIC table as described by Anderson et al. ([Suggestions for Presenting the Results of Data Analyses. J.Wildl Manage. 65(3): 2001](http://digitalcommons.unl.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1227&context=usgsnpwrc)). To do so, I have been using `ICtab` in the `bbmle` package.

```
aic2 <- ICtab(du1500o,du1500a,du1500b,du1500c,du1500d,du1500e,du1500f,
              du1500g,du1500h,du1500i,du1500j,du1500k,du1500l,
              type="AICc", weights=T,delta=T,sort=T,base=T,nobs=87)
```

This gives me a nice little ranked table.

```
        AICc  df dAICc weight
du1500a 402.4 6    0.0 0.4201
du1500k 403.4 6    1.0 0.2580
du1500j 404.4 6    2.0 0.1520
du1500f 405.6 6    3.2 0.0842
du1500g 406.8 6    4.4 0.0459
du1500e 408.7 6    6.3 0.0176
du1500d 410.2 6    7.8 0.0084
du1500l 410.7 6    8.3 0.0065
du1500i 412.3 6    9.9 0.0030
du1500o 412.4 4   10.0 0.0029
du1500c 415.2 6   12.8 <0.001
du1500h 416.6 6   14.2 <0.001
du1500b 416.6 6   14.2 <0.001
```

I want to add the log likelihood of each model to this table. I can extract one log likelihood at a time with the `logLik` function. However, I have been unable to find a more efficient away to extract the LL from all of the models.

```
head(logLik(du1500a))
[1] -194.6726
```

1. Should I turn `aic2` into a data frame? How?
2. If so, how can I then efficiently append the LL of each model to that data frame?

Much appreciated,
Nava

Comment: It would be good to have a reproducible example.  You can say `modelList <- list(du1500o,du1500a,du1500b,...)` and then `logLikvec <- sapply(modelList,logLik)`.  It will be best to produce an *unsorted* table, so that you can more easily match up the log-likelihoods with the correct models, then sort the table by min AIC.  (I should add an option to `ICtab()` to include the log-likelihood in the table ...).  (I'd also like to encourage you to leave the `AICc` column *out* of your table and include just the `delta-AICc` column ...)

Comment: Thanks, Ben. That worked for me, and I was able to tease everything into place.

Comment: for what it's worth, I just added this feature to the latest version of `bbmle` 1.0.15, which went up on CRAN last night (it might not have propagated to all mirrors yet) ... you should be able to add `logLik=TRUE` to your command